Div (inside another div) won't fill entire width despite 100%?
I'm trying to make the div box look like this:
box that has a green stripe at the top and the rest is cream
I'm using two div boxes to achieve this appearance, but the inner div just won't fill the width no matter what I mess with.
HTML
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Pixel Paws</title>
<body>
    
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#">Username</a>
      <a href="#">My Clan</a>
      <a href="#">Messages</a>
      <a href="#">Trades</a>
      <a href="#">Bookmarks</a>
      <a href="#" style="float:right">Pixel Paws</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>Welcome</h2>
          <div class="textbox" style="height:200px;">welcoming message</div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h2>Announcements</h2>
          <h5>Date Posted | Sep 2, 2017</h5>
          <div class="textbox" style="height:500px;">some filler text here</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rightcolumn">
        <div class="card">
          <h3>My Account</h3>
          <div class="textbox" style="height:100px;">account information</div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
          <div class="textbox"><p>post</p></div>
          <div class="textbox"><p>post</p></div>
          <div class="textbox"><p>post</p></div>
          <div class="textbox"><p>post</p></div>
          <div class="textbox"><p>post</p></div>
          <div class="textbox"><p>post</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>Staff Assistance</h3>
          <div class="textbox"><p>some more text</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      wikki / credits / media / etc
    </div>
</body>

CSS
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #3F4438;
}

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #E8E2DD;
  position: sticky;
  top: 14;
  height:60px;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #2C2E3D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #2C2E3D;
}

/* CONTENT BOXES */

.leftcolumn {   
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}
.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #3F4438;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
h2, h3, h5 {
  color:#2C2E3D;
}

/* TEXT BOXES */

.textbox {
  background-color: #E8E2DD;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #2C2E3D;
}

/* RIGHT COLUMNS */

.card {
  background-color: #A3AB96;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* FOOTER */

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E8E2DD;
  color: #2C2E3D;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}


Hi, please post the entire code. You mentioned two div boxes but on your code there is only one. Also you use clases on your css that are not used on the html

Sorry! Just added the rest of my code after I realized my error

The parent class card has a padding of 20px which fills the space around your textbox.
If you remove that it will span the entire width.

Thank you so much, I don't know how I missed that! >.>
